# angular how to define multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i have code like this

angular.module('mywidget', ['$scope']).controller('TestController', testController);

I want to add another controller to it ..say ...controller("Test2Controller",Test2Controller)

just wanted to know how we can achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can

```
var myApp = angular.module('mywidget', ['$scope']);
myApp.controller('TestController', testController);
myApp.controller('Test2Controller', test2Controller);
```