# AngularJS Error: Argument 'FirstCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently doing the egghead.io AngularJS course and have run into an issue a few others seem to have.
Any solutions I have come across here aren't working for me though.
In the second video the instructor is showing how to connect controllers to ng-apps. I have followed the video exactly, restarted a few times, and tried solutions on here. 
I am given the following error console:

[image: Error: 'FirstCtrl' is not a function, got undefined]

In the long list of errors there, I have picked out the first as as saying:

"FirstCtrl' is not a function, got undefined"

Anyone know of a solution?
Was something changed in the Angular spec in regards to assigning controllers, or is this course skipping information?

**Code:**

```js
function FirstCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    message: "Hello"
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Angular App</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Condensed:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
      <h1>You said:</h1>
      <h3>{{data.message}}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Marc - looks like you don't really have a controller set up yet - just a function. Check out this page to see how you would add a controller to your angular app: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: Did you declare your module and put your controller there somewhere?

Comment: As far as I know app.controller(); is used instead of function firstctrl().

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular how to define multiple controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100755/angular-how-to-define-multiple-controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your exemple working (Run the exemple ...).

1. Add you app name.
2. Declare your controller using angular.controller.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('FirstCtrl', FirstCtrl);

function FirstCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    message: "Hello"
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Angular App</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Condensed:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
      <h1>You said:</h1>
      <h3>{{data.message}}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

An Angular controller is defined like this :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]); //Your app

//The controller in the myApp module, first param is the controller's name
//Second is the controller's dependencies
app.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    //Do whatever you want in this controller
    $scope.data.message = 'Hello!';
}]);
```

Then you bind your controller to the view (your HTML) using the `ng-controller` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the part where you define your controller.

You can definitely  have your FirstCtrl be a function. You just need to first define that the FirstCtrl is a controller.

Example:

```
angular.module("app").controller("FirstCtrl", FirstCtrl);
```

And then you have your FirstCtrl function:

```
function FirstCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
  message: "Hello"
 };
}
```

You also need to include that file in your html scripts

```
<script src="mypath/firstctrl.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing problem when defined controller just like a simple JavaScript function and then I downgraded the cdn link version for angular from "1.4.5" to "1.2.28" and it started recognising controller (A simple javascript function). Also you have to include the .js file in which you have created your controller in your html file . Actually they have deprecated the use of simple javascript function as a controller from angular 1.3 version.